# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have this in Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private IsAdapter isAdapter;
    private List<Is> isList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        isList = new ArrayList<>();
        isAdapter = new IsAdapter(this, isList);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(isAdapter);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);
    }
```

I'm using my own theme (which is material), It was working well, then I made some changes in the code, now I get this error. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

My manifest file I have this : `android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">`

I googled, the solutions say change `AppCompatActivity` to `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`. When I do that, I get error at these lines :

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Here is my styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: post yor `styles.xml` file here.

Comment: @Ironman I added, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

to this

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Full code :**

```
<resources>   

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and then `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Comment: @jason see my answer below.

Comment: @jason see my full code you have only this code in `styles.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" to your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, You have already defined a style `MyMaterialTheme` in `values/styles.xml`.
Does Your most base theme extends one of the `Theme.AppCompat.{Light,Dark}.NoActionBar`? For example:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: In Your project You should have a file `app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

Comment: Change the line with `MyMaterialTheme.Base` to the one in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

change these two lines

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Use these

```
setActionBar(mToolbar);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```